# modifying a HTML.erb form using query selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom, devise

I'm trying to autofill a login form for a demo rails app. using devise for the authentication. I have the basic form for an HTML.erb file here:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field" name="email">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field" name="password">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
```

and in my js files I'm trying this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var email_input = (document.querySelector('div[name="email"]').value =
    "demouser@mail.com");
  var password_input = document.querySelector('div[name="password"]');
  password_input.value = "password"
})
```

I learned that if you wrap your selectors in a 'DOMcontentLoaded' eventListener you can get this current code to work. My problem is now how to go deeper and select the rails email and password fields. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

never mind I checked the html in devtools and turns out its just a input tag. swapped div for input and it works. thanks